# Proper sentence structuring: "They would even throw him under the bus if it means that they could make more money."

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, paraphrasing

How do I say this thought properly?

> They would even throw him under the bus if it means that they could make more money.

Can anyone help me to find the right words for this?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that phrasing, though I assume it is hyperbolic.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it as: They would go to such extremes like throwing him under the bus if they thought that it would make them more money.

Answer (score 0):

Some possible rephrasings:

If you are sure they can do a certain thing, then use 'would'. If you are predicting possibilities of the same thing happening, use 'could'.

> They **would** even go to the extent of throwing him under the bus if it means that they **could** make more money out of it.

> They **could** even go to the extent of throwing him under the bus if it means that they **could** make more money out of it.

> They **would** even go to the extent of throwing him under the bus if it means that they **would** make more money out of it.

> They **could** even go to the extent of throwing him under the bus if it means that they **would** make more money out of it.

---

> They **would** even go to the extent of throwing him under the bus if they **think** they **could** make more money out of it.

> They **could** even go to the extent of throwing him under the bus if they **think** they **could** make more money out of it.

> They **would** even go to the extent of throwing him under the bus if they **think** they **would** make more money out of it.

> They **could** even go to the extent of throwing him under the bus if they **think** they **would** make more money out of it.